# pointers with structs in structs c

Tags: c, struct

I have tried to create a CD `struct` like :

```
typedef struct
{
  char* nameCD;
  int yearOfpublication;
  song* listOfSongs;
  int priceCD;
  int numberOfSongs;
} CD;
```

and I have a song `struct` :

```
typedef struct
{
  char* nameSong;
  char* nameSinger;
  int lenghtOfSong;
} song;


void SongInput(song *psong, CD *pcd)
{
pcd->numberOfSongs++;
pcd->listOfSongs = (song*)malloc(pmcd->numberOfSongs*sizeof(song));

// here all the code that update one song..
```

but what should I write to update the next song?

how do I change it into an array which update the number of the songs and how can I save all the songs?

I tried this :

```
printf("Enter lenght Of Song:");

scanf("%d", &psong->lenghtOfSong);
```

but I don't understand the pointers.. 
and how to update the next song?

```
}

void CDInput(CD *pcd)
{
  int numberOfSongs = 0;
  //here all the other update of cd.
  //songs!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
  pcd->numberOfSongs = 0;
  pcd->listOfSongs = (song*)malloc(numberOfSongs*sizeof(song));
}
```

Do I need to write anything else?

Comment: Standard Warning : Please [do not cast](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917) the return value of `malloc()`.

Comment: and, you need to use `realloc()` to resize the memory and add the new value to it.

Answer (score 2):

```
void CDInput(CD *pcd)
{
    int i;
    //...
    printf("Enter number Of Song:");
    scanf("%d", &pcd->numberOfSongs);
    pcd->listOfSongs = (song*)malloc(pcd->numberOfSongs*sizeof(song));
    for(i = 0; i < pcd->numberOfSongs; ++i){
        SongInput(&pcd->listOfSongs[i]);
    }
    //...
}
```

Comment: a little bit of explanation wouldn't hurt :-/ code-only answers [sucks](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272/is-there-any-benefit-to-allowing-code-only-answers-while-blocking-code-only-ques).

Comment: I respect the original. It is not a mistake.

Comment: Answer is subjective, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on if you want to write the structure once completely or you really want to add one item.

For the first case, please refer to [BLUEPIXY's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27685640/296974), for the second one, thigs are slightly more complicated.

```
bool add_song(song *psong, CD *pcd)
{
    song* newone = realloc(pcd->listOfSongs, (pmcd->numberOfSongs+1)*sizeof(song));
    if (!newone) {
        // return and complain; the old remains intact.
        return false; // indicating failure.
    }
    // now we can assign back.
    pcd->listOfSongs = newone;
    newone[pcd->numberOfSongs++] = *psong;
    return true; // indicating success.
}
```